# Error al cargar vue en laravel: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

Estoy comenzando a utilizar vue. Primero hice mi proyecto en laravel, de ahí ejecute el comando `npm install` y finalmente `npm run dev`. Pero al momento de cargar el componente en mi vista, no se muestra nada y aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi webpack mix tengo el siguiente código:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

y en mi app.js tengo el siguiente

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

y finalmente en mi vista tengo el siguiente código para cargar el componente y el app.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        ejemplo de componente
        <div id="app">
            <example-component></example-component>
        </div>
    </body>

<script src="{{asset('resources/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: No debes referenciar directamente a resources/js/app.js. `require` es utilizado por webpack, que es una herramienta que agrupará tus assets js en un solo archivo. Entonces, como en webpack.mix.js tienes `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')`, el js compilado se guardará en `/public/js/app.js` y la referencia la debes hacer a ese archivo: `<script src="{{asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>`